# Getting a Parse error while executing a Twilio file to perform an action when a user calls the number

Tags: php, xml, twilio, twilio-php

I am getting a parse error:

```
12100 Document parse failure
Description:vError on line 1 of document  : Premature end of file.  Please ensure that the response body is a valid XML document.
```

I am not sure why is this error happening. My code is below. Could you please tell me what may be the root cause of this error.

```
<?php

    header("content-type: text/xml");
    require "twilio-php-latest/Services/Twilio.php";
    $server= "http://ea3473a.ngrok.com";
        /* Set our AccountSid and AuthToken */
    $AccountSid = "AC043519349d0042fc190fe61870e591cd";
    $AuthToken = "19b05608d0e1b9b7ccda615f6620f388";
    $caller=$_REQUEST['From']; 

    echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n";
    $from= "+17864310795";
    $client = new Services_Twilio($AccountSid, $AuthToken);
    try {
            $to = $caller;            
            $url = $server.'/trial.php';
            $client->account->calls->create(
            $from, 
            $to, 
            $url,
            array( 
            'Method' => "GET", 
            'FallbackMethod' => "GET", 
            'StatusCallbackMethod' => "GET", 
            'Record' => "false", 
            ));
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            // log error
        }
?>
<Response>
     <Reject reason="busy"/>
</Response>
```

Comment: From your question it's not clear where the error happens. Please only put the minimum code needed to demonstrate the issue into your question. Apart from that the error message seem somewhat detailed. Which part of it you have problems to decipher? And I bet you've contacted the support of the vendor of that Webservice. What could they tell you about the error code 12100? Were they able to track the error with your requests?

Comment: Just seeing, the error is easily explained, it's in the docs: https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/12100 - This has also been asked before. I fear the only person who can give more information is yourself. Either on how you interpreste the error message or just the fundamental questions about the terms used in the error message and/or the docs. You should be able to clarify any of those terms with existing Q&A material on site. If not, edit the question and provide the addtional reference information that didn't made it for you and explain why.

Comment: Tip: Validate the document before you send it.